AWS Textract Custom Model access
Anyone who have experience in using a custom aws Textract model in you application. I have developed the aws Textract custom model. But unlike Rekogntion and Comphrend I could not find the ARN plus I couldn't access the model in my application. I have various version including the following:
Specify the ARN of the custom model you want to use
custom_model_arn = 'arn:aws:textract:us-west-2:123456789012:model/custom-model'

Call Textract with your custom model ARN
textract = boto3.client('textract')

# Here, we simulate sending the adapter information
# This part should be replaced with the actual method to include the adapter information
response = textract.analyze_document(
    Document={'Bytes': document_bytes},
    FeatureTypes=['FORMS'],
    CustomFeatures={
        'AdapterId': adapter_id,
        'AdapterVersion': adapter_version
    }
)

or
textract = boto3.client('textract')

# Here, we simulate sending the adapter information
# This part should be replaced with the actual method to include the adapter information
response = textract.analyze_document(
    Document={'Bytes': document_bytes},
    FeatureTypes=['FORMS'],
    CustomFeatures={
        'AdapterId': adapter_id,
        'AdapterVersion': adapter_version
    }
)

However both could not work
